# How to make a flex column put under another?

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I need to have one column placed under the other when viewed on a cell phone.
I am using bootstrap 4 and the divs are flex, I use flex columns and flex rows, already using the property property order and it did not work.

My code

```
<div id="menu-text" class="d-flex flex-row">

        <div class="d-flex flex-column col-sm justify-content-center">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row menu-subtitle">Sashomi  </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row menu-small-text">[CORTE DE MARISCOS O CARNE CRUDOS]</div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row menu-mini-text">[FRESH BEEF OR NATURAL SEAFOOD]</div>
          <img src="images/BrochazoBlanco.png" class="white-brush">

          <div class="d-flex flex-row">

            <div class="d-flex flex-column col-md-3">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">$ 72</div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-column col-md-3">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">$ 50</div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-column col-md-6">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">Sushi california</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex flex-column col-sm justify-content-center">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row menu-subtitle">Sashimi</div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row menu-small-text">[CORTE DE MARISCOS O CARNE CRUDOS]</div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row menu-mini-text">[FRESH BEEF OR NATURAL SEAFOOD]</div>
          <img src="images/BrochazoBlanco.png" class="white-brush">

          <div class="d-flex flex-row">

            <div class="d-flex flex-column col-md-3">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">$ 72</div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-column col-md-3">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">$ 50</div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-column col-md-6">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row">Sushi california</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I already researched about it, and I already tried several things like the order class that gives you bootstrap, grid-template-areas, wrapping, etc. If I post it here it's because I could not do it, although it's easy I'm learning and I'm new in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check [this example](http://jsbin.com/getoporuwe/edit?html,output) for a simplified, responsive version of the code that you provided.**

<s>I don't know how many columns you need, as you didn't give any code, but here is a three column grid that is responsive.</s>

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-secondary">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-danger">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-success">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the same thing [here](http://jsbin.com/dasuholisa/edit?html,output), and resize the output to see how it works.

Comment: I already put the code, it did not work out what you told me, thank you.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsbin.com/getoporuwe/edit?html,output) a simplified version of what you're probably wanting to achieve. Try to resize that.

Comment: Yes it works, but i am using flex-box for columns and rows.

Comment: The Bootstrap 4 grid system **uses** flexbox. ([source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/))

Comment: Then you do not need to write flex-colum or flex-row, any row or column are flex when you use bootstrap 4?

Comment: That's true. The Bootstrap 4 grid uses flex by default.